# How to set splash screen for iOS in PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen, phonegap-cli, launchimage

I am using `PhoneGap` for creating `iOS` application for `iOS9+`. As per guide line I have added following code in `Config.xml` to set the splash screen.

```
// set the cordova plugin 
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="&gt;1.0.0" />

 // set splash screen for iPad only
 <platform name="ios">
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="2048" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="2048" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1536" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
</platform>
```

Then I used following command in 'Terminal' to generate iOS platform

```
phonegap build ios --device
```

It copies all the splash images in `iOS` platform.

But it show default `Phonegap` splash screens image when I launch the app. I checked in iOS project 'Images.xcassets'-> '`LaunchImage`, it is showing default `PhoneGap` images. It is not showing splash Image which I mentioned in Config.xml file. How do I set the splash images using `config.xml` for `iOS`?

Comment: Show or hide the Splash Screen using ngCordova plugin `$cordovaSplashscreen`

Comment: Check this http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/splashscreen/

Comment: check this too https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/

Comment: I have checked link https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/ , I tried both ways i.e. 'Legacy launch images' and 'Launch storyboard images' as mentioned in doc, still it is showing default Phonegap splash screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First add the **Splash screen** plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

Then in **config.xml** add these lines.

```
<!-- iOS splash screen -->
<!-- iPad -->
<splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait.png" platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape.png" platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />
<!-- Retina iPad -->
<splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x.png" platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x.png" platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />

<!-- Default splash screen -->
<splash src="splash.png" />
```

Make sure of the image **width** and **height** should be same as it is defined in config.xml.

or try **default splashscreen.**

Just keep full size splash screen image where your config.xml is located it will copy the splash.png file for all platform it is not recommended this will increase the app size but you can check if that works.

Cheers.

Comment: I have already installed 'cordova-plugin-splashscreen' plugin in project. Also I have crosschecked the image size, it is correct as expected. Still showing the default phonegap splash screen image

Comment: write the lines exactly i have written in the config.xml and then try it.

Comment: I am developing application for iPad only. Can you please provide me detail  for iPad?

Comment: solution works for me, but need to remove the iOS platform first using command 'phonegap platform remove ios' and then add it using command 'phoengap build ios --device'

Answer (score 0):

You need to change/replace the image files in splash screen directory (www/res/screen/ios/).
By default it contains images of phone gap